# Get the buttons that have checked property set

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I have one scenario where a radio button once submitted shall remain default checked and also the check boxes that were previously selected should also be disabled. Suppose now i set the checked="checked" for two of them. The question is how can i check this checked property for these two so that i can disable them. Can any one help me with the code.

```
<div class="element">
    <input id="product_id---0" type="radio" value="2-2" checked="checked" data-second_price="0.00" data-first_price="1000.00" name="product_id">
    <input id="product_id---1" type="radio" checked="checked" value="3-3" data-second_price="0.00" data-first_price="2000.00" name="product_id">
    <input id="product_id---2" type="radio" value="4-4" data-second_price="0.00" data-first_price="3000.00" name="product_id">
    <input id="product_id---3" type="radio" value="5-5" data-second_price="0.00" data-first_price="4000.00" name="product_id">
</div>
```

I tried the following code but it is not working. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
$product_ids = document.getElementsByName( 'product_id' );


for( i=0; i < $product_ids.length; i++ ) {
    alert( $product_ids[i].checked );

}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain further? I am not able to understand the question. The code you have posted does do what is expected of it. (By the way, you are using radio button, so only one from a group can be checked at any given point).

Comment: If you need 2 options selected, you need a checkbox not a radio.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. there is no code for the group of checkbox. Improve it please.

Comment: This is the only designed system where a user selects any level to upgrade and he is upgraded to that level. so we can't have check boxes in that case. I found the checked property for these radio box marked as checked as the user goes to next level. Having check boxes was easy but i can't change the existing system. that is why i posed the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `radio` input who can be only one selected from group at time, if you want two options selected you need a `checkbox`  input.

<kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PHNQG/1/)</kbd>

```
$product_ids = document.getElementsByName('product_id');

for( i=0; i < $product_ids.length; i++ ) {
    $product_ids[i].disabled = $product_ids[i].checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property i.e. `disabled` on the checkbox you want to render as disabled.

Answer (score 0):

As Oswaldo noted, you are using the incorrect input type, it should be `type="checkbox"` I assume since you tagged this question with jQuery, we can use it in the answer. Here is what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/PHNQG/2/

### HTML

```
<div class="element">
    <input id="product_id---0" type="checkbox" value="2-2" checked="checked" data-second_price="0.00" data-first_price="1000.00" name="product_id">
    <input id="product_id---1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="3-3" data-second_price="0.00" data-first_price="2000.00" name="product_id">
    <input id="product_id---2" type="checkbox" value="4-4" data-second_price="0.00" data-first_price="3000.00" name="product_id">
    <input id="product_id---3" type="checkbox" value="5-5" data-second_price="0.00" data-first_price="4000.00" name="product_id">
</div>
<button id="disable">Disable</button>
<button id="enable">Enable</button>
```

### JS

```
$('#enable').click(function(){
    $( ".element input:checked" ).attr( "disabled", false );
});

$('#disable').click(function(){
    $( ".element input:checked" ).attr( "disabled", true );
});
```

Good luck!